# Nexus 7 and Samsung Ace S5830i does not connect properlly to Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have three devices:

1. Tablet running on Android 4.0 (Nexus 7)
2. Smartphone running on 2.0 (Samsung Ace S5830i)
3. HP Compaq laptop

Wireless router does have WPA/WPA2 PSK security. And the Wifi works perfectly fine on the laptop.

Now both the tablet and the phone does connect to the Wifi but at times does not allow me to browse or do anything. i.e cannot download anything.

My tablet keeps getting disconnected and then it re-connects back automatically, this happens randomly and erratically. Same experience with the Android phone.

I called the telecoms engineer and he resetted the router etc., and said there has to be something wrong with my tablet!!! But I am sure there is not.

I have browsed through some posts which suggests me to change MAC settings and to change the encryption settings, but I have no idea what that is, nor where to find it.

Would love if this could be sorted as its really frustrating.

Meanwhile I understand Nexus 7 runs on 2.4Ghz Wifi band frequency, where as most of the modern routers comes with 5.0Ghz Wifi band frequency, but then, again my smartphone runs on the 5.0Ghz Wifi band frequency, and still doesn't function!!

So help guys!!

Comment: Some Android devices have problems when set to WPA/WPA2 PSK. Chosing one of both (i.e. fix the device to one of both) is reported to help.

Comment: The 5Ghz frequency, that's the newer Wifi draft right, a/b/g/n, its n is the latest... perhaps the wifi chipset on the Nexus does not incorporate the 802.11n...?